# Stock AnyChart, floating crosshair datetime representation

Tags: stock, anychart

I have a 15M candle stock chart, with a floating crosshair. I want the `xLabel` of the crosshair to display the the date and time of the candle at crosshair position.

By default, the `xLabel` shows *only* the date component. First I tried to fix that by explicitly formatting the label

```js
stockChart.crosshair().xLabel().format('{%value}{dateTimeFormat:d MMM \'\'yy HH:mm}');
```

but this just gives me the same time for all positions; midnight

Next, I've read about the `{%rawValue}` token, so I tried that

```js
stockChart.crosshair().xLabel().format('{%rawValue}{dateTimeFormat:d MMM \'\'yy HH:mm}');
```

Now I got a working time component on the label, but it's calculated based on the x-position of the crosshair on the chart, and not based on the timestamp of the candle it's pointing at.

I tried tinkering with the `rawValue` with the callback method on `format()` to round the timestamp accordingly:

```js
stockChart.crosshair().xLabel().format(function(){
    var s = Math.floor(this.rawValue/1000);
    return Math.floor((s+450)/900)*900;
});
```

(I had to offset the timestamp by 7.5 minutes first to get the 'flip' positions right)

I do get the timestamp I want now, but I lose the formatting capabilities of AnyChart for using a callback function. I'd have to do my own formatting in plain javascript. This seems like a lot of hassle for something relatively simple.

Ideally I would like to use same label as the tooltip title shown next to the crosshair. However I am not able to grab it; the `title().text()` method should, according to the [docs](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.core.ui.Title#text), return the text, but

```js
stockChart.crosshair().xLabel().format(function(){ return candleSeries.tooltip().title().text(); });
```

gives me an empty string.

I am fairly new to AnyChart, and I've buried my head deep in the available documentation, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

See snippet below for a working example, with the `xLabel` based on formatted `rawValue`.

```js
var dataSet = [
  [1661601600000,20211.5,20238.6,20211.3,20226.7,4.12648731,20151.15554002],
  [1661602500000,20231.2,20242.7,20211.4,20211.4,3.42244709,20151.41467878],
  [1661603400000,20211.4,20211.4,20189.6,20189.6,11.69463657,20151.97707839],
  [1661604300000,20190.3,20197.8,20170,20190.6,72.26967752,20154.40330817],
  [1661605200000,20191.2,20194.8,20169.4,20169.4,20.15687644,20154.85913391],
  [1661606100000,20169.6,20182.9,20120,20143.9,34.09454775,20154.67060591],
  [1661607000000,20146.7,20233.2,20101.8,20199.2,33.20240788,20155.37368634],
  [1661607900000,20201,20220,20166.9,20172.1,3.91859194,20155.48310242],
  [1661608800000,20172.3,20197.9,20172.2,20174.8,12.9596617,20155.78522112],
  [1661609700000,20174.7,20209.9,20174.7,20203.5,13.30573245,20156.25703591],
  [1661610600000,20205.2,20205.2,20137,20139.7,9.34910624,20156.29278801],
  [1661611500000,20139.4,20149.5,20045.3,20050,64.74889239,20152.29303056],
  [1661612400000,20061.7,20095,20045,20092,33.56191969,20150.26858129],
  [1661613300000,20092.3,20093,19971.9,19980.2,46.00547856,20145.44083531],
  [1661614200000,19984,20016.8,19829.1,19913,149.4883454,20121.97008058],
  [1661615100000,19904.5,20045.1,19853.7,19984.6,41.01155027,20117.51083081],
  [1661616000000,19984.4,20025.1,19928,19939.9,61.73807722,20111.37377287],
  [1661616900000,19940,19957,19848.3,19889.3,27.07076618,20107.69347307],
  [1661617800000,19889.2,19933.3,19876.7,19907.1,20.00892669,20105.1483828],
  [1661618700000,19905.2,20022.4,19905.2,20007.4,14.59560004,20103.99343746],
  [1661619600000,20007.5,20027.7,19981.9,20013.1,26.62525382,20102.41762632],
  [1661620500000,20014.8,20027.7,19997.9,20006.1,23.6331589,20101.10432667],
  [1661621400000,20005.5,20099.7,20001.9,20071.9,38.59464698,20100.11700622],
  [1661622300000,20071.3,20071.3,19992.3,19992.3,35.16042289,20098.45771039],
  [1661623200000,19992.4,20000.1,19992.3,19992.4,6.22365406,20098.08589736],
  [1661624100000,19992.4,19994.7,19961.2,19986.2,14.0667922,20097.14066995],
  [1661625000000,19978.6,20020.7,19975.7,19979.7,8.04716411,20096.65871635],
  [1661625900000,19982.9,19983.4,19953.5,19960,7.06273872,20096.13352975],
  [1661626800000,19960,19974.6,19936.2,19964.1,18.02193901,20094.73805462],
  [1661627700000,19963.4,20005.8,19957.7,19982.7,38.87461654,20092.33001841],
  [1661628600000,19984.2,20006.3,19978.3,20005.3,18.1326274,20091.38545109],
  [1661629500000,20005.7,20046.7,19982.2,20018.2,12.80123187,20090.86170155],
  [1661630400000,20017,20037.3,20005.6,20029.8,11.85313563,20090.43749437],
  [1661631300000,20029.2,20029.2,19966.7,19966.7,48.39776075,20087.83015226],
  [1661632200000,19966.8,19976.8,19951,19968.1,2.97437214,20087.63964902],
  [1661633100000,19968.1,20018.7,19957.4,20010.9,3.48680904,20087.4723237],
  [1661634000000,20014.6,20019.5,19978.9,20013.9,5.88419625,20087.21714114],
  [1661634900000,20013.9,20022.2,19985.9,19985.9,28.01177026,20085.93584815],
  [1661635800000,19986.9,19997.9,19976.8,19978.3,3.36083049,20085.76107973],
  [1661636700000,19980,19980,19875.4,19883.9,23.66230514,20083.69505555],
  [1661637600000,19875.3,19933.3,19864.9,19911,13.85812645,20082.43803742],
  [1661638500000,19911,19949.6,19882.3,19935.5,22.06586246,20080.68485012],
  [1661639400000,19935.6,20088.6,19924.2,20038.1,23.60370217,20079.94652617],
  [1661640300000,20038.2,20081.4,20010,20030.5,8.53763395,20079.78244344],
  [1661641200000,20030.5,20030.5,19996.8,20023.4,5.80133216,20079.60460968],
  [1661642100000,20023,20050.4,20001,20038,5.88547638,20079.46212636],
  [1661643000000,20048.7,20081.9,20031.3,20055.7,9.58415667,20079.35472084],
  [1661643900000,20057,20062.1,20029.1,20032.7,7.77417583,20079.21211848],
  [1661644800000,20032.9,20037.6,19994.3,20036,6.18290337,20022.63333333],
  [1661645700000,20036,20043.8,19963,19980.4,13.42461351,20004.21579961],
  [1661646600000,19986.1,19986.1,19936,19936.1,6.8318603,19990.9128759],
  [1661647500000,19937.1,19986.2,19935.7,19986.2,5.37533028,19987.27248439],
  [1661648400000,19986.2,20010.4,19971.6,20001.1,11.57774997,19989.16531724],
  [1661649300000,20010.4,20078.2,20009.1,20054,7.23195073,19997.44157737],
  [1661650200000,20048.5,20069.5,20037.9,20068.4,6.67911561,20004.57000768],
  [1661651100000,20068,20068,20020.3,20020.5,4.57113362,20006.91167177],
  [1661652000000,20020.7,20052.4,20020.3,20026.2,75.83222595,20021.25959841],
  [1661652900000,20026.3,20087.1,20026.2,20087.1,1.12340192,20021.62810716],
  [1661653800000,20088.5,20154.8,20081.1,20081.1,39.67539332,20040.30685693],
  [1661654700000,20081.2,20081.2,20008.6,20008.7,9.30384658,20039.93662801],
  [1661655600000,20008.7,20055.8,20002.6,20046.5,8.66084535,20039.7175412],
  [1661656500000,20046.5,20047.8,19983.6,19988.3,8.26790173,20038.37881655],
  [1661657400000,19990.2,20022.2,19984.5,20019.8,55.08499449,20032.11489415],
  [1661658300000,20018.6,20018.6,20000,20000,2.57033186,20031.86103934],
  [1661659200000,19999.9,20000.4,19981,19985.5,5.60347859,20030.96417247],
  [1661660100000,19985.4,19996,19968,19968,6.85176549,20029.62719783],
  [1661661000000,19968,19998.2,19966,19991.1,5.88886549,20028.69317767],
  [1661661900000,19991.2,20000.4,19984.6,19996.7,0.76741931,20028.59832698],
  [1661662800000,19996.6,20017.8,19992.7,20001.4,2.01221733,20028.42350785],
  [1661663700000,19997.3,20010.3,19950.8,19969.9,2.54167338,20027.96660297],
  [1661664600000,19964.8,19987.9,19964.8,19982.4,2.74937934,20027.49442474],
  [1661665500000,19981.2,20059.3,19966.2,20059.2,6.74507182,20027.51128799],
  [1661666400000,20059.2,20074.1,20026.8,20074.1,2.36116853,20027.75557287],
  [1661667300000,20071.6,20071.6,20055.1,20058.7,2.12075602,20027.99621089],
  [1661668200000,20048.3,20059.1,20037.9,20044,13.04182904,20028.78784999],
  [1661669100000,20048.6,20057.1,20037.4,20037.7,10.61424347,20029.28886128],
  [1661670000000,20037.9,20044.9,20019.1,20021.5,4.83947101,20029.27724085],
  [1661670900000,20022.8,20072.1,20022.8,20047,20.33124269,20030.32758425],
  [1661671800000,20047,20070.6,20040.3,20064.6,0.77726327,20030.39021273],
  [1661672700000,20067.9,20077.6,20044.9,20056.6,6.53051516,20030.92761911],
  [1661673600000,20053.1,20098,20049.5,20080.4,7.78281908,20031.89074065],
  [1661674500000,20085.6,20098,20078.2,20087.2,6.55965038,20032.88057302],
  [1661675400000,20087.3,20087.3,20033.6,20033.6,6.09200202,20033.18176328],
  [1661676300000,20033.7,20034.4,20009,20029.2,10.43639944,20032.93957366],
  [1661677200000,20022.1,20029,20022.1,20029,1.53435564,20032.91493564],
  [1661678100000,20029,20029,20028,20028.9,11.40373051,20032.79286361],
  [1661679000000,20029,20029,20028.7,20029,4.11757202,20032.75319698],
  [1661679900000,20029,20029,20000,20026.1,20.66633117,20032.05323741],
  [1661680800000,20026.2,20026.2,19973.8,20005.8,15.62072794,20030.98486228],
  [1661681700000,20005.8,20005.8,19959.3,19964.1,85.68831902,20022.09390004],
  [1661682600000,19964,20006.5,19964,20002.2,48.19334132,20019.47605335],
  [1661683500000,20002,20011.9,19982.9,19989.8,3.1673824,20019.34106385],
  [1661684400000,19992.3,20022.6,19956,19986.3,3.1950052,20019.17025495],
  [1661685300000,19974,20011.4,19969.5,20002.8,3.95067781,20019.00397978],
  [1661686200000,20000.4,20022,20000.4,20010.2,6.82777091,20018.91003467],
  [1661687100000,20013.9,20026.2,20003.5,20026.1,3.56108927,20018.908179],
  [1661688000000,20026.2,20049.5,20026.1,20034.7,31.10986503,20019.79557008],
  [1661688900000,20034.5,20034.5,19980,19997.2,3.91021985,20019.69690907],
  [1661689800000,19998.5,20011.1,19981.2,19990.5,6.76583675,20019.42669934],
  [1661690700000,19988.6,19988.6,19980.3,19983.5,0.73827439,20019.38582633]
];

var stockData = anychart.data.table();
stockData.addData(dataSet);

var stockChart = anychart.stock();
stockChart.crosshair().displayMode("float");
stockChart.crosshair().yLabel().format('{%rawValue}{decimalsCount:1}');
stockChart.crosshair().xLabel().format('{%rawValue}{dateTimeFormat:d MMM \'\'yy HH:mm}');

// mappings
var ohlcMapping = stockData.mapAs();
ohlcMapping.addField('open',  1);
ohlcMapping.addField('high',  2);
ohlcMapping.addField('low',   3);
ohlcMapping.addField('close', 4);
ohlcMapping.addField('value', 5);

var vwapMapping = stockData.mapAs();
vwapMapping.addField('value', 6);

var priceMapping = stockData.mapAs();
priceMapping.addField('value', 4);

stockChart.plot(0).yGrid(true).xGrid(true).xMinorGrid(true).yMinorGrid(false);
stockChart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:dd MMM \'\'yy hh:mm}');
stockChart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:hh:mm}');
stockChart.plot(1).xAxis().labels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:dd MMM \'\'yy hh:mm}');
stockChart.plot(1).xAxis().minorLabels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:hh:mm}');

// Candlestick chart
var candleSeries = stockChart.plot(0).candlestick(ohlcMapping);
candleSeries.name('BTC');
candleSeries.legendItem().iconType('rising-falling');
candleSeries.minLabels(true);
candleSeries.minLabels().position('low').format("{%low}").fontSize(9);
candleSeries.maxLabels(true);
candleSeries.maxLabels().position('high').format("{%high}").fontSize(9);

// VWAP chart
var vwapSeries = stockChart.plot(0).spline(vwapMapping);
vwapSeries.name('VWAP');
vwapSeries.legendItem().iconType('circle');
vwapSeries.zIndex(15);

// Volume chart
var volumeSeries = stockChart.plot(1).height(100).legend(false).column(ohlcMapping);
volumeSeries.name('Volume').fill(function(){ return this.iterator.get('close') < this.iterator.get('open') ? '#fc5164 0.5' : '#32da80 0.5' });

// Scroller chart
var scrollerSeries = stockChart.scroller().line(priceMapping);

stockChart.container('chart_stock');
stockChart.draw();
```

```css
#chart_stock {
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-stock.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_stock"></div>
```

Comment: There appears to be no way whatsoever to get the data associated to the candle under the crosshair or mouse cursor in a stock chart. I have tried about every angle to get what I need. The only solution that works in any situation is using the callback function on `format()` method, and round the x-axis timestamp to the candle period, then format it with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

All of the effort you’ve put into formatting your example is valuable. We think you will achieve the required behavior if you  [set crosshair display mode](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Crosshair#display_mode) to "sticky" in order to display the date and time of a crosshair position point.

```
stockChart.crosshair().displayMode("sticky");
```

You can try out the [sticky crosshair behavior](https://playground.anychart.com/S5j2f9JW/0) of your example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `sticky` display mode was actually one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately for my use case I need the crosshair at the mouse pointer, not at the candle itself. Ideally I want best of both worlds; free floating crosshair, and direct access to the metadata associated to the candle closest to or under the crosshair. My solution with a customized label and some `rawValue` magic does the job for now.